# How to extend Class instance

Tags: python, monkeypatching

`MyClass` is defined in `module.py`. There is no way we can modify it. But we do know the Class definition looks like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def method(self, msg):
        print 'from method:', msg
```

I start my script with importing the module and then declaring an object's instance:

```
import module    
foo = module.MyClass()
```

Then I write my own function:

```
def function(msg):
    print 'from function:', msg
```

Now, every time `foo.method('')` is used I want to call `function()` so it prints the same message too.

Would this situation be referred as the `monkey patching`? How to achieve what is needed?

Comment: Subclass it and override `method()` and call base class's `method()` using `super()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just creating a subclass?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am not able to subclass or inherit from `MyClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called monkey-patching.

This is basically decoration, but done manually after the class is already defined.

```
from functools import wraps

def wrapper(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        myFunction()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

MyClass.printThis = wrapper(MyClass.printThis)
```

It will affect all instances of `MyClass`, even those that were created before the patch was applied.

**If you don't need to dynamically modify runtime behaviour, avoid monkey-patching** and **prefer to use inheritance** to customise behaviour, as suggested in the comments.  It's less hacky.

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass it as well:

```
class MyClass:
    def method(self, msg):
        print 'from method:', msg

def function(msg):
    print 'from function:', msg

class MyNewClass(MyClass):
    def method(self, msg):
        function(msg)
        MyClass.method(self, msg)
```

And use it like:

```
>>> a = MyNewClass()
>>> a.method("test")
from function: test
from method: test
```

Or, if you want to make your class a "new-style" class (for Python 2 - judging by your print statements) - just have `MyClass` inherit from `object` and then you can user `super`:

```
class MyClass(object):  # object added here
    def method(self, msg):
        print 'from method:', msg

def function(msg):
    print 'from function:', msg

class MyNewClass(MyClass):
    def method(self, msg):
        function(msg)
        super(self.__class__, self).method(msg)  # super added here
```

Comment: I'd probably call it with `super(MyNewClass, self).method(msg)`  not sure it will work with your invocation scheme (method is not a classmethod)

Comment: @boatcoder super doesn't work (in Python2) unless the class is a new style class (OP's example isn't and is py2 based on prints). Added example if they want to adjust to new style :)

Comment: Good catch on that old style class, I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to [wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41904233/1636276) that also involves monkey-patching. However, it does it through functionality provided by `unittest.mock`. The advantage of this approach is that a context manager is used to automatically apply and remove the patch within a limited scope:

```
from unittest import mock

# This class would be defined in some third-party library
class MyClass:
    def method(self, msg):
        print('from method:', msg)


def function(msg):
    print('from function:', msg)


old_method = MyClass.method


def new_method(self, msg):
    old_method(self, msg)
    function(msg)


# The patch is only applied within this scope
with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'method', new_method):
    foo = MyClass()
    foo.method('message with patched')

# By this point MyClass is "back to normal"
print('---')
foo.method('message with original')
```

**Output**

```
from method: message with patched
from function: message with patched
---
from method: message with original
```

Answer (score -1):

Ended up with this solution till there is better one posted...

```
class MyClass:
    def method(self, msg):
        print 'from method:', msg

def function(msg, callback):
    print 'from function:', msg
    callback(msg)

foo = MyClass()
foo.function = function
foo.function(msg='message', callback=foo.method)
```

Comment: How is this calling `function()` every time `method()` is invoked?

Comment: Here it is `method()` that is being called via `callback` every time `function` is called.